# Google Sheets Sentiment Analysis error over API key

Tags: google-sheets-api, sentiment-analysis

Hi I've been trying to do some sentiment analysis from google sheets. Here is my code:

```
function getSentiment(text) {
  var apiKey = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
  var url = "https://language.googleapis.com/v1/documents:analyzeSentiment?key=" + apiKey;
  var data = {
    document: {
      type: "PLAIN_TEXT",
      content: text
    }
  };


  var options = {
    method: "post",
    contentType: "application/json",
    headers: {
      "Authorization": "Bearer " + apiKey
    },
    payload: JSON.stringify(data)
  };
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  var result = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
  return result.documentSentiment.score;
}
```

Here is what comes up:

```
Error
Exception: Request failed for https://language.googleapis.com returned code 401. Truncated server response: { "error": { "code": 401, "message": "Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or othe... (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response) (line 18).
```

I think the key is right (changed here for obvious reasons) and enabled so I'm not sure where I go from here. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: I think that the API cannot be used for the POST method while the API key can be used for the GET method. I'm worried that this situation might be due to the reason for your current issue. But, from your script, I cannot know your `apiKey`, because in your script, `key=" + apiKey` and `"Authorization": "Bearer " + apiKey` are used. I apologize for this. If your `apiKey` is the access token, please use it in the request header.

Comment: Thank you for that, it makes sense. Any idea where I might find the code for how to do that?

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from your reply, I couldn't understand your situation. When I could correctly understand your situation, I would like to think of a solution.